# After creating a session (passport,node js,express-session) how to access the session variables from another file inside same project

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, express, session-variables

After cerating a session in login.js file, the session can be accessed from the routes inside the login.js file.
login.js

```
router.use(bodyParser.json()); 

router.use(session({
    secret: 'Our secret',
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true
}));

router.use(passport.initialize());

router.use(passport.session());

router.get('/sess', (req,res) =>{
  const sess = req.user.username
  res.json(req.session);
  res.redirect('/student_profile');
})
```

however if i try to access it from another file in same directory eg: student.js it is showing null
student_profile.js

```
router.get('/', (req,res) =>{
    res.json(req.session); //not showing anything
 }
```

What can I do to access the session details from this files ?

Comment: How is student.js imported and used in your main app?

Comment: IN server.js 
const student_profile = require('./routes/student_profile');
app.use('/student_profile', student_profile);

Comment: It is used for defining routes under /student_profile category

Comment: The order of `.use()` calls is important. You should put all session related calls in the main server file, then include the routes below that. Putting the session stuff only into your login file doesn't make much sense in general, even if it worked that way: while a session is started by a login, it is used by all routes.

Comment: @ChrisG Thanks a lot! It is working fine now. I have moved all the session related calls in my server.js files and it is working fine now :-)